# Continuity of superposition operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Let $E$, $F$ be Banach spaces, $D$ be open in $E$, and $K=[0,1]$. Given $\varphi\colon K\times D\to F$ 
$$
\varphi^\sharp\colon D^K\to F^K,\quad  u\mapsto \varphi(\cdot,u(\cdot))
$$
is known as the *superposition operator*.

I am interested in the regularity of $\varphi^\sharp$ as a function on $C(K,D)$ where $C(K,D)$ is equipped with different $p$-norms and $\varphi$ is assumed to be sufficiently regular.

E.g., I can show that 
$$
\varphi^\sharp \in C^k\left(\left(C\left(K,D\right),\Vert\cdot\Vert_p\right),\left(C\left(K,F\right),\Vert\cdot\Vert_q\right)\right)\tag{$\star$}
$$

if $p=q=\infty$, $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$, and $\varphi$ and $\partial^k_2\varphi$ are continuous. Can someone comment on the validity of $(\star)$ in dependence of $\varphi$ and $k$ for other values of $p$ and $q$? Any resources?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by $p$-norm? is there some measure here? also, in order to have $\varphi^\#$ acting from continuous $**to**$ continuous functions, isn't it necessary to assume that $\varphi$ is jointly continuous?

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Yes, just take the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Concerning the other point, yes, sorry, you may assume $\varphi$ to be continuous and e.g. differentiable in the second argument, whatever may help. See the edit.